# how to insert array values into the column of a database table?

Tags: php, sql, database, arrays

I have an array with three values red, green and yellow. Now i should

```
insert red into column3 row1
insert green into column3 row2
insert yellow into column3 row3
```

How can i do that i tried writing the code

```
foreach ($output as $value)
{
    echo ($value.'<br>');
    $tstring = implode(',' , $output);
    $insert_col= "UPDATE INTO `5` (B) VALUES ('$tstring')";
    $insert_result = mysql_query($insert_col);
    if ($insert_result)
    { 
        echo ("RECORDED!")|
        exit();
    }
}
```

but it does not work. it is filling extra rows to the existing table  with a value R.

Please help!

Comment: What about connecting to your DB before trying to query? Also, don't use `mysql_*`, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Comment: This doesn't `$insert_col= "UPDATE INTO \`5\` (B) VALUES ('$tstring')"`; make any sense. I doubt that your table name is "5", further you need to tell the database which column to update by a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i did the connection part before itself i have not mentioned that code here, since the code will be lengthy.

Comment: i specified the column name as (B).. sorry i m a newbie, dont know much about that... fine i ll try using "WHERE" thanks

Comment: I've a question though: why is there an implode? If I have understood, you want to update each row with a value from the array, not with all the values of the array.

Comment: @vicrabb No i want to update with all  the values of the array

Comment: okay thanks for clearing the doubt :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I remember correctly, an UPDATE statement should have a WHERE clause.

Like:

```
 UPDATE table SET column_name='value' WHERE condition;
```

You can find examples [at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

As for inserting the right value:

```
foreach($output as $value){
     $tstring = $value;
     $insert_col = "UPDATE `5` SET B='" . $tstring . "' WHERE insert a condition here";
     $insert_result = mysql_query($insert_col);

    if ($insert_result) {
         echo ("RECORDED!") |
    }
}
```

You don't want to insert all your array in one row, which means that the implode is useless.

And I repeat, **you need a WHERE clause** here. Without it, you'll update all your rows with the same values.

Comment: Good spot. WHERE is optional, yet, without it all rows will be set to the new value, which is rarely intended.

Comment: Thanks i tired using the following command but it dint work :(           **$insert_col= "UPDATE `5` SET column_name='B' WHERE VALUES ('$tstring')";**

Comment: No no, the code should be: "UPDATE 5 SET B='".$tstring."' WHERE id=1" for example. id=1 is an example, I don't know your table.

Comment: it works...! but i dont know why it filling the values "R" in all the fields  :( where i m going wrong ...!! :(

Comment: Well, do perhaps an echo of $tstring to see if in this variable, it's R recorded.

Comment: yes i did that long back but the values are printed fine. **RMS: 3.221, RMS: 1.848, RMS: 2.925, RMS: 3.880, RMS: 3.880, RMS: 3.880** i.e. **array[0] =RMS: 3.221, array[1] =RMS: 1.848** and so on

Comment: no all the values of the array and i used the command as suggested by you **$insert_col= "UPDATE `5` SET B='".$tstring."'";**

Comment: ups I deleted my comment as you did answer the question above. Well, I don't see why it's recording the first letter of your string, can you show us your new query (in case of there would be something missiny)?

Comment: i am sorry but its the same query i have written :( **$insert_col= "UPDATE `5` SET B='".$tstring."'";** and the code is same as above

Comment: yes gotit!! :) but i am really very sorry to bug you so much... its only print the first value of the array getting printed in all the fields

Comment: You don't bug me, unfortunately, right now, I don't know why it's only the first value that's printed. Perhaps someone with better knowledge when it comes to database will know. Maybe you should ask a new question or search if a similar question exists.

Comment: I'm updating my answer since I've seen your last post and since we misunderstood each other about the implode.

Answer (score 1):

You got couple of errors. Looks you forgot to connect to the database and also you `exit()` after 1st successful insert. So if you got more elements in array, these will not be stored. You may also want to display value of `mysql_error();` in case of failure